# Obtaining all companies from CRM Dynamics using fetch XML

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, xrm

I'm running the following code to access CRM Dynamics DB.

```
using (OrganizationServiceProxy proxy 
  = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, null, credentials, null))
{
  const String request = @"
    <fetch mapping ='logical'>
      <entity name = 'account'>
        <attribute name = 'name'/>
      </entity>
    </fetch>";

    FetchExpression expression = new FetchExpression(request);
    EntityCollection result = proxy.RetrieveMultiple(expression);
    ...
}
```

I'm fairly sure that `organizationUrl` and `credentials` are correct. According to [this walk-through](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/01/26/using-a-console-app-to-fire-a-crm-2011-workflow.aspx), the other two can be set to `null` for this simple case.

The problem is that when I get to the last line, retrieval to `result`, I get `Exception` telling me that:

> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
>
> Message=Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: CurrentServiceEndpoint

What did I forgot and how do I resolve this problem?

EDIT:

> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
>
> HResult=-2147467261
>
> Message=Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: CurrentServiceEndpoint
>
> Source=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk
>
> ParamName=CurrentServiceEndpoint
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.ClientExceptionHelper.ThrowIfNull(Object
>   parameter, String name)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.CreateChannelFactory(ClientCredentials
>   clientCredentials)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration.CreateChannelFactory(ClientCredentials
>   clientCredentials)
>
> at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1.get_ChannelFactory()
>
> at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1.CreateNewServiceChannel()
>
> at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1.ValidateAuthentication()
>
> at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1.get_ServiceChannel()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceContextInitializer`1.Initialize(ServiceProxy`1
>   proxy)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceContextInitializer`1..ctor(ServiceProxy`1
>   proxy)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContextInitializer..ctor(OrganizationServiceProxy
>   proxy)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultipleCore(QueryBase
>   query)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase
>   query)
>
> at CRM_Server_Accessor.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\Viltersten\documents\Software\Projects\CRM_Server_Accessor\Program.cs:line
>   60
>
> at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)
>
> at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>
> InnerException:

Comment: Is there a stack trace to go with that?

Comment: On-premise or CRM Online (or hosted?)

Comment: Also, it may be just a typo (it's worth me checking), but your code snippet sends `organisationUri` to `OrganizationServiceProxy` constructor, but your post refers to `organisationUrl` (which makes me sound a bit pedantic ;) )

Comment: I tested Online version. I was expecting something like `SecurityAccessDeniedException` if the creds were wrong... That's what I got when I tried the hosted version, namely. But the online barks about argument null for end point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Service Reference` in your project, pointing to your organization's org service.

URL would be  like this: `http://yourCRMserver/yourOrganization/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc`

Name it, say, `OrganizationService`.

Then, in your code you would proceed like this:

```
using (OrganizationService.OrganizationServiceClient client = new OrganizationService.OrganizationServiceClient())
{
    const String request = "<Your FetchXml query goes here>";
    FetchExpression expression = new FetchExpression(request);
    EntityCollection result = client.RetrieveMultiple(expression);
    //...
}
```

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675404.aspx) provides a good sample code about authentication including Online.

Comment: `OrganizationService` turns ill red in VS meaning there's no such class... Intellisense doesn't seem to know what to add in `using` section to remedy it... I've read the article but it's a way of an overkill for my case. I'm just creating a proof of concept. Just a quick log-in and fetch.

Comment: Did you perform all the steps, or simply copy-pasted the code ?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear - my bad. I've read through the code but it occurred to me that there's got to be a shorter way (not the most stable and recommended, though). The article [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/01/26/using-a-console-app-to-fire-a-crm-2011-workflow.aspx) describes a guy who made it work in a very few steps so I was trying to adapt his solution. Am I to understand that the article you mentioned **is** indeed the minimal code needed? (It's a little bit scary...)

Comment: The example you linked looks like it's based on an On-Premise environment. Online works a bit differently, and (but my experience is *very* limited when it comes to CRM Online) might require in fact more code. I understand that authentication process is more complex, due to the recent Office 365 auth integration and AD federation (but, again, I don't have experience with it).

Comment: But what's that `OrganizationService` class? My VS10 can't find it. Is it something special ouside `MS.Xrm` namespace?

Comment: That's the name of the service reference to the CRM organization service (see above in the beginning of my answer). It doesn't have to be `OrganizationService`, of course, any valid name will do, it was just an example.

Comment: Ah, so clumsy... The site colored the name using blue and it starts with upper case so I got fooled to believe that it's a static class name, hihi. Of course, you're right...